# Typescript: can a generic function make use of the type variable?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Just read the section on generic functions in typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

**Q:** I want to know if you can have different behavior based on the **type variable(s)** passed to the generic? e.g.:

```js
interface GenericIdentityFn<T> {
  (arg: T): T;
}

function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  // based on the "lexical" value of T, not necessarily the "typeof " of `arg`?
  if(<T> is "TypeA") console.log('A!')
  else if (<T> is "TypeB") myArray.push(arg)
  else arg.foo += 1
  return arg;
}

let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn<number> = identity
```

Putting aside whether this might be incredibly silly / useless or not, is this sort of single interface, differentiated behavior possible in typescript?

Comment: No, static type system information like interfaces and generics are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is emitted to JavaScript, which is what runs at runtime.  There is no `<T>` at runtime, so it can't be done as written.  The right way to think is: "what do I want the JavaScript to do, and then how can I write types for it in TypeScript?"  If you had to do this in pure JS, what would you do?  Pass in a constructor and use `instanceof`?  Something else?

Comment: @jcalz (I suspected it was a silly question but didn't think through WHY - reading your comment makes it clear why, lol). Underlining its silliness, is the fact I don't even have a use case for this. It's just I read about generics, thought "wow this is so cool", then kept thought-experimenting when I should have stopped.